# C++ incrementing global counter variables in if-else statements

Tags: c++, if-statement, nested, counter, global

so my overall goal is to make a program that would display the color associated with the wavelength number inputted by the user (400 to 445 is violet, etc.). The input needs to be between 400 and 700, and let the user know if the input is to high or to low. I also need to implement a global counter variable that will count out and display the amount of comparisons performed between the users input and the range of colors (for every else statements it goes through, increment 1). Here's what I have so far.
CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int g_counter;

int main()
{
g_counter = 0;
int userinput;

cout<< "please enter wavelength between 400 and 700: "<< endl;
cin>>userinput;
++g_counter;
if (userinput < 400){
    cout << "Wavelength to small, try again"<< endl;
    
    cout << "You evauluated this many conditions: "<< g_counter << endl; 
}
++g_counter;
else (userinput >= 400 && userinput <=445){
    cout<<  "Your wavelength corresponds to the color violet"<< endl;

    cout << "You evauluated this many conditions: "<< g_counter << endl; 
}
++g_counter;
else (userinput > 445 && userinput <= 475){
    cout<< "Your wavelength corresponds to the color blue"<< endl;
    
    cout << "You evauluated this many conditions: "<< g_counter << endl; 
}
++g_counter;
else (userinput > 475 && userinput <= 510){
    cout<< "Your wavelength corresponds to the color green"<< endl;
    
    cout << "You evauluated this many conditions: "<< g_counter << endl; 
}
++g_counter;
else (userinput > 510 && userinput <= 570){
    cout<< "Your wavelength corresponds to the color Yellow"<< endl;

    cout << "You evauluated this many conditions: "<< g_counter << endl; 
}
++g_counter;
else (userinput > 570 && userinput <= 590){
    cout<< "Your wavelength corresponds to the color Orange"<< endl;
    
    cout << "You evauluated this many conditions: "<< g_counter << endl; 
}
++g_counter;
else ( userinput > 590 && userinput <= 700){
    cout<< "Your wavelength corresponds to the color red"<< endl;
    
    cout << "You evauluated this many conditions: "<< g_counter << endl; 
}
++g_counter;
else ( userinput > 700 ){
    cout<< "wavelength to large, try again"<< endl;

    cout << "You evauluated this many conditions: "<< g_counter << endl; 
}

return 0;
}
```

My issue is I can't make sense of the errors I get when I compile it.
ERRORS:

```
Homework2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Homework2.cpp:19:1: error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’
 else (num >= 400 && num <=445){
 ^
Homework2.cpp:19:31: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
 else (num >= 400 && num <=445){
                               ^
Homework2.cpp:26:1: error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’
 else (num > 445 && num <= 475){
 ^
Homework2.cpp:26:31: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
 else (num > 445 && num <= 475){
                               ^
Homework2.cpp:32:1: error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’
 else (num > 475 && num <= 510){
 ^
Homework2.cpp:32:31: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
 else (num > 475 && num <= 510){
                               ^
Homework2.cpp:38:1: error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’
 else (num > 510 && num <= 570){
 ^
Homework2.cpp:38:31: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
 else (num > 510 && num <= 570){
                               ^
Homework2.cpp:44:1: error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’
 else (num > 570 && num <= 590){
 ^
Homework2.cpp:44:31: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
 else (num > 570 && num <= 590){
                               ^
Homework2.cpp:50:1: error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’
 else ( num > 590 && num <= 700){
 ^
Homework2.cpp:50:32: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
 else ( num > 590 && num <= 700){
                                ^
Homework2.cpp:56:1: error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’
 else ( num > 700 ){
 ^
Homework2.cpp:56:19: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
 else ( num > 700 ){
                   ^
```

for example, the error "Homework2.cpp:19:1: error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’" doesn't make sense to me because there is a previous if. Also, the global counter (when the program worked before I mucked it up)kept giving the answer of 1 even if it actually checked more comparisons. Any pointers on the issues would be fantastic.

Comment: Are you expecting all 8 of those `++g_counter;` lines to execute every time?

Comment: yes Drew, if the input was larger than the range of the else statement, the counter is supposed to increment 1 to express that the comparison was done.

Comment: You seem to be confused about the syntax of [if statements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if). `else` is part of the if-statement, not a separate construct. You can only have _one_ statement between `if` and `else`, which is usually a compound statement enclosed by `{` `}`.

Comment: Since each `else` condition checks for the opposite of the previous condition, it looks like you can just replace all those `else` with `if` and it should be fine.

Comment: Thank you @FrançoisAndrieux that fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `else` command must be **inmediately** preceded by an `if(){}` block. Setting a `g_counter` in betwwen makes next `else` an error.

To count comparisons you can use the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) which returns the result of the evaluation of `E2` in `(E1,E2)`

So you can code like this:

```
if (++g_counter, userinput < 400){
    cout << "Wavelength to small, try again"<< endl;
    
    cout << "You evauluated this many conditions: "<< g_counter << endl; 
}

else if ((++g_counter, userinput >= 400) && (++g_counter, userinput <=445)){
    cout<<  "Your wavelength corresponds to the color violet"<< endl;

    cout << "You evauluated this many conditions: "<< g_counter << endl; 
}

else....
```

Note the parentesis when `&&` is used (two comparisions)

Comment: I think this differs from the intended behavior because `g_counter` would be incremented twice by certain `else if`s.

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that "else" must be __immediately__ preceded by an "if".  I think there was confusion because all else statement _did_ occur after an if-statement, for some definition of "after".

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It depends on if the OP defines 'comparisons'  as the conditions inside if-blocks or the amount of `<`,, `>` etc operators executed.

Comment: @Ripi2 Seems to me like OP wants to increment `g_counter` exactly once between each branch, taken or not.

Comment: You could delete the `(++g_counter, userinput >= 400) &&`  part since you know its true if you get into the else {} that would get rid of the extra comparison and extra increment to g_counter

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, that's better code. But I left it there just to ilustrate how to count 'comparisons'

Comment: This worked thank you, the comparison result was doubled as said in the other comments, but i just divided the output by 2 so the code works, thank you @Ripi2

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that a if/else construct should look like this:

```
if (...) 
{ ... /* then case code */ }
else 
{ ... /* else case code */ }
```

with nothing between the "}" at the end of the "then case code" and the "else" that starts the else branch.

In your case above you have a "g_counter++" between those two components, which doesn't form a valid if/else construct.

Comment: OK, the directions I was given said "define a global2
counter variable at the beginning of the program.  Increment this variable immediately before each condition that is checked." Where would I increment the g_counter if that is the incorrect spot?

Comment: @ChunkierLizard See Francois Andrieux's comment under your question.